# ARC semantic Issue No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, xcode5

I creat a new project, select Master-Detail Application ,and select 'Use Core Data'
then build the new project.  (XCode 5.0) this error:
ARC semantic Issue  No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
    }
}
```

the error:

```
 [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because its a method on table view data source and not the table view. Also, the correct signature of the `UITableViewDataSource` method is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and not `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

So your call should actually be,

```
 [self configureCell:[datasource tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
 // If datasource is self, replace with self
```

Hope that helps!